# Neo4j to Oracle real time data sync

Tags: oracle, neo4j

In one of the use cases in my application there is a requirement to publish neo4j transaction data to oracle database in real time. I did google on it, but couldn't find a tool or plug-in which can help. Everywhere on internet talks about rdbms to neo4j sync. So I am planning to do this by manually invoking jdbc commands.

Can you please suggest something?

Comment: Since you mention 'realtime' data sync, it is better to use a system in between to temporarily store data for retries, failures etc. Kafka came to my mind first. there may be other options as well. but you may need to roll this on your own. Here is link to neo4j-kafka integration https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/ and https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/#_kafka_connect.  From oracle https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/event-hub-cloud/admin-guide/kafka-connect1.html .

Comment: forgot to mention, in my previous company the source data for our neo4j instance came from an oracle rdbms. Kafka was used to sync data between the two. But data models and usecases were different for these databases. So, we had to write code to properly construct the neo4j nodes and relationships from the oracledata before uploading.

Comment: @blackrain would have chosen your comment as answer. Not sure that is allowed.

Comment: thx. appreciate your comment. happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to write my own jdbc code.